# Single regex expression which can validate a comma separated strings to match a particular format

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a single regex expression which can validate a string which has comma separated sub-strings. The expression should return a "match" **only** if all the sub-strings are in a particular format. It should return 0 matches if **even one** sub-string is not in the required format.

Required Format of sub-string: **digit:apples**

*Example 1*
50:apples,20:apples,30:apples
*Result should be:* **Match**

*Example 2*
50:apples,20:apples,30:oranges
*Result should be:* No match

*Example 3*
50:apples,20:oranges,30:apples,40:apples
*Result should be:* No match

I am looking for a single regex expression which can achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should the empty string be a match?

Comment: No. Empty string should not be a match.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. You are expected to post the attempt you made and then ask for help getting it to work.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to StackOverflow. This is my first post. I have tried this ([^,]+)\d:apples    but it matches each sub-string which matches the format. But, I want a match only if all sub-strings are in the required format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\d+:apples(?:,\d+:apples)*$
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  But, It does not return a match.    http://regexr.com/3cgc2

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  My bad I missed a ":" in the expression.  Its working!!